# How to move a value from field1 to field2 using Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I would like to move value in field1 to field2. Purpose is to after that delete the column 'field1' to get a better column naming standard /Jan

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange!  I think this one is fairly easy to answer from a Google search that found this [**help page**](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Calculating_field_values).

Comment: You could also use the 'table manager' plugin to just rename the existing column.

Answer (score 2):

You can select to change the field 2 on the right side and click on the left side bottom of the list for data field 1.

Both fields should have the same data type.

Comment: Thx Andre! that was a quick answer and worked fine! /Jan